# Type can't be resolved. Its indirectly ref from required .class files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

That error is shown when trying to create Feed object inside RSSFeedParser class in tomcat 8

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [23] in the jsp file:hello.jsp The type
>   Feed cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required
>   .class files
>
> 22:   <% RSSFeedParser parser = new
>   RSSFeedParser("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss");   23:
>   Feed feed = parser.readFeed();
>
> An error occurred at line: [23] in the jsp file: hello.jsp The method
>   readFeed() from the type RSSFeedParser refers to the missing type Feed
>   20:   <% String src = request.getParameter("src"); %> 21:     <%= src %>
>   22:   <% RSSFeedParser parser = new
>   RSSFeedParser("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss");   23:
>   Feed feed = parser.readFeed();

What have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check WEB-INF/lib folder. You may miss a JAR file with the Feed class.

Comment: The /lib dir is empty...fyi am noob here. So do i have to jar all the classes am using and put it there?

Comment: Did you create Feed class yourself or you are using some library? You classes should be in the WEB-INF/classes folder. All libary JARs have to be in the WEB-INF/lib folder. If it's your class, try to find it in the WEB-INF/classes. If it's library class, find the library JAR and put it in the WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Its a class I created and still exists in the /classes dir. Can import it in jsp but when creating an object that creates the Feed class that error is shown...

Comment: Do you have this error when you running application from Eclipse or then you run Tomcat outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I run tomcat outside eclipse. Though i did'nt import Feed inside RSSFeedParser since they're on the same dir

Comment: Try to import Feed class or import all classes in the package like: <%@ page import = "java.io.*" %>. Mind the star (*) at the end of the package name.